# Django admin does not allow saving unicode slugs

Tags: django, django-admin, python-unicode

I'm trying to save a Persian slug for this model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField('slug', unique=True)
    description = models.TextField('description')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('category_detail', None, {
            'slug': self.slug
        })

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name
```

But Django does not save the page and complaint that:

```
Enter a valid 'slug' consisting of letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens
```

I also tried to use this save method instead

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.name = slugify_unicode(self.name)
      super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

but it did not solve the problem. So I got stock on this and appreciate your help to resolve this.

Comment: but, what value are you trying to save?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. [`Slug` fields can only contain ASCII letters, numbers, dashses and underlines](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7a1/django/core/validators.py#L150-L151).

If you must use non-ASCII chars in a slug-like field, you can use a normal `CharField` and add a `db_index = True` to it.